# Free storage space in amazon open search data node is low and others nodes has more than enough free space

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, elasticsearch, helpdesk

In my AWS open search i am using 8 data nodes (r5.2xlarge.search) and 3 master nodes (r5.large.search) and each data nodes has allocated to a space of 200gb each. And also added my shard value as 4.When i checked the open search dash board i could see that free space in one data node is very low but the other nodes had more space compared to this data node. How do evenly distribute the data in each node.

[image]

This is my shard count distribution in the existing data node and if i increase or decrease the shard count, will that solve this storage issue.
[image]

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/opensearch-rebalance-uneven-shards/